# Check each value in one column with each value of other column in one dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
dict = {'val1':["3.2", "2.4", "-2.3", "-4.9","0"], 
        'class': ["1", "0", "0", "0", "1"],
       'val2':["3.2", "2.7", "1.7", "-7.1", "0"]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(dict) 
df
    val1    class   val2
0   3.2     1       3.2
1   2.4     0       2.7
2  -2.3     0       1.7
3  -4.9     0      -7.1
4   0.0     1       0.0
```

I want to check two things:
1) for the sign: if the sign of record in column val1 is not same with the sign of column val2 (for example: sign of the values at index 2 is not same), in this case change the sign of value 2 to the sign of value 1. Desired output is like this:

```
    val1    class   val2
0   3.2     1       3.2
1   2.4     0       2.7
2  -2.3     0      -1.7
3  -4.9     0      -7.1
4   0.0     1       0.0
```

2) Second check: if the value in val2 column is within the interval between value in val1 column +2 and -2. For example: record at index 2: 2.4 is in the range [2.7+2: 2.7-2]. If condition is true then i want to change class from 0 to 1. Desired output is :

```
    val1    class   val2
0   3.2     1       3.2
1   2.4     1       2.7
2  -2.3     1      -1.7
3  -4.9     0      -7.1
4   0.0     1       0.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First convert values to floats if necessary and then set sign with [`numpy.sign`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sign.html) and then for second use [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html):

```
df['val1'] = df['val1'].astype(float)
df['val2'] = df['val2'].astype(float)

df['val2'] *= np.sign(df['val1']) * np.sign(df['val2'])
df['class'] = df['val2'].between(df['val1'] - 2, df['val1'] + 2).astype(int)
#alternative
#df['class'] =  np.where(df['val2'].between(df['val1'] - 2, df['val1'] + 2), 1, 0)
print (df)
   val1  class  val2
0   3.2      1   3.2
1   2.4      1   2.7
2  -2.3      1  -1.7
3  -4.9      0  -7.1
4   0.0      1   0.0
```

Comment: as far as I see if val1 is positive and val2 is negative it won't change the sign of val2.

Comment: @Boendal even if the sign of val1 is positive and in val2 it is negative. val2 should change its sign to sign of val1

Comment: @Boendal - Answer was edited  7 minutes ago. `df['val2'] *= np.where((df['val1'] < 0) & (df['val2'] > 0), -1, 1)`

Comment: @Boendal to do vice verse you can change signs df['val2'] *= np.where((df['val1'] > 0) & (df['val2'] < 0), -1, 1)

Comment: yeah it works if val1 is positive but if val1 is negative and val2 is positive it wont' work anymore

Comment: as shown here: https://repl.it/repls/FinancialDeadlyStatistic the last row is val2 still negative and is a copy of your solution.

Comment: @Boendal - Understand, then is necessary use `df['val2'] *= np.sign(df['val1']) * np.sign(df['val2'])`

Comment: @jezrael what does *= part do in df['val2'] *= np.sign(df['val1']) * np.sign(df['val2'])? why not to use simple = sign?

Comment: @Sascha - It is shorcut - it is same like `df['val2'] = df['val2'] * np.sign(df['val1']) * np.sign(df['val2'])`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
# Check 1
df['val2'] = df.apply(lambda x: np.sign(x['val1']) * np.sign(x['val2']) * x['val2'], axis=1)

# Check 2
df['class'] = df.apply(lambda x: int(abs(x['val1'] - x['val2']) < 2) , axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will solve your query without using any other library:

```
def signfunc(x,y):
    if x*y >= 0:
        return y
    else:
        return -1*y

df['val1'] = df['val1'].astype(float)
df['val2'] = df['val2'].astype(float)
df['val2'] = df.apply(lambda x: signfunc(x.val1, x.val2), axis=1)
print(df)

df.loc[abs(df["val1"]-df["val2"])<=2, 'class'] = 1

print(df)
```